# How to upsample a PyTorch tensor?

Tags: pytorch

I have a PyTorch tensor of size `(1, 4, 128, 128)` (batch, channel, height, width), and I want to 'upsample' it to `(1, 3, 256, 256)`

I thought to use [interpolate](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#interpolate) (a function in nn.functional)

However, reading the documentation, and applying this function I am able to get in output a shape `(1, 4, 256, 256)`, so maybe it is not the function that I am looking for. The code that I used is the following:

```
import torch.nn as nn
#x.shape -> (1,4,128,128)
x_0 = nn.functional.interpolate(x, scale_factor=2, mode='bilinear', align_corners=False)
#x_0.shape -> (1,4,256,256)
```

How can I do that (from `(1, 4, 128, 128)` to `(1, 3, 256, 256)`)?

To follow there is the network that I am trying to replicate, but I got stack in the upsample layer.

[image]

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? What are your four and three channels (input and output, respectively) corresponding to exactly?

Comment: I added a picture, I hope that this could be clarify a bit my question

Answer (score 2):

Lots of papers miss small details such as this. With no context it's hard to say exactly what they are doing, but I would assume that they are doing both upsampling and adjusting the number of channels.

Adjusting the channels happens typically with a learnable pointwise convolution layer. Modifying your example:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

input_channels = 4
output_channels = 3

upsample_layer = nn.Sequential(nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2,
                                           mode='bilinear',
                                           align_corners=False),
                               nn.Conv2d(input_channels,
                                         output_channels,
                                         kernel_size=1,
                                         padding=0,
                                         bias=False)
                               )

x0 = torch.rand([1,4,128,128])
x0 = upsample_layer(x0)
print(x0.shape)
```

Outputs the torch.Size([1, 3, 256, 256]) you want.

Toggle bias on or off depending if you have a normalization layer after this or not.

Answer (score 0):

What about PyTorch's `nn.Upsample` function:

```py
upsample = nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2)
x = upsample(x)
```

Not sure if that's what you are looking for since you want the second dimension to change from 4 to 3.